# Pass a filename as variable PHP

Tags: php

When I request this URL:

http://example.com/csv_build.php?filename=test.txt&time=1485902100000&data=25

I expect the PHP code to create a file named : `datafile.txt` that will contain the following data:

```
test.txt,1485902100000,25<CR><LF>
```

For some reason, `datafile.txt` is not created.

Did I made a mistake ?

```
 <?
 # GRAB THE VARIABLES FROM THE URL
 $File = 'datafile.txt';
 $FileName = $_GET['filename'];
 $HeureTronconMesure = $_GET['time'];
 $DonneeCapteur = $_GET['data'];
 # --------------------------------

 $FICHIER = fopen($File, "a");

 #ftruncate($FICHIER,0);

 fputs($FICHIER, $FileName);
 fputs($FICHIER , ",");
 fputs($FICHIER, $HeureTronconMesure);
 fputs($FICHIER , ",");
 fputs($FICHIER, $DonneeCapteur);
 fputs ($FICHIER , "\r\n");

 fclose($FICHIER);  
 ?>
```

Comment: Writing file contents from data supplied directly from the querystring seems like a bad idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing any error checking. Why do you assume everything will work okay? If you spot some errors, first thing I would check is file permissions.

```
<?php
 # GRAB THE VARIABLES FROM THE URL
 $File = str_replace("/", "_", $_GET["filename"]);
 $FileName = $_GET['filename'];
 $HeureTronconMesure = $_GET['time'];
 $DonneeCapteur = $_GET['data'];
 # --------------------------------

 if (!$FICHIER = fopen($File, "a")) {
     //there was an error opening the file, do something here
 }

 fputs($FICHIER, $FileName);
 fputs($FICHIER , ",");
 fputs($FICHIER, $HeureTronconMesure);
 fputs($FICHIER , ",");
 fputs($FICHIER, $DonneeCapteur);
 fputs ($FICHIER , "\r\n");

 fclose($FICHIER);  
 ?>
```

Though really, I'd simplify this code immensely by using [some shortcuts](http://php.net/file-put-contents) and concatenating strings.

```
<?php
// replace any slashes in the filename with underscores
$file = str_replace(["/", "\\"], "_", $_GET["filename"]);

// build a string out of your data
$data = "$_GET[filename],$_GET[time],$_GET[data]\r\n";

// write the data to the file, checking if it returns false
if (!file_put_contents($file, $data)) {
    //there was an error writing the file, do something here
}
```

Note, never open your code with `<?`, it's been deprecated a very long time now. Use `<?php`.

Comment: What do you mean by filename needs to be escaped ?  can you show me please ?

Comment: It's in the answer

Comment: Do you mean I should add quotes " " or declaring that variable differently ?  sorry but ´escaped' does not talk to me , I'm very newbie

Comment: I have escaped the filename in the answer I provided, to prevent anyone passing a filename with a `/` or ` \ ` in it. I was merely pointing it out.